# Combine multiple table and use Group By Function in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 different datasets from 5 different tables.. From those 5 different tables I have taken below group by data..

```
select number,count(*) as total from tb01 group by number limit 5;
select number,count(*) as total from tb02 group by number limit 5;
```

Like that I can retrieve 5 different datasets. Here is an example.

```
+-----------+-------+
| number    | total |
+-----------+-------+
| 114000259 |     1 |
| 114000400 |     1 |
| 114000686 |     1 |
| 114000858 |     1 |
| 114003895 |     1 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Now I need to combine those 5 different tables such as below tabular format.

```
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
| number    | tb01  | tb02  | tb03  |
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
| 114000259 |     1 |     2 |     1 |
| 114000400 |     1 |     0 |     1 |
| 114000686 |     1 |     3 |     1 |
| 114000858 |     1 |     1 |     5 |
| 114003895 |     1 |     0 |     1 |
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Can someone help me to combine those 5 grouped data sets and get the union as above.

Note: I dont need the header as same as table names..these headers can be anything
Further I dont need to limit 5, above is to get a sample of 5 data only. I have a large dataset.

Comment: UNION ALL and do another GROUP BY.

Comment: `JOIN ON number` to combine all the tables you want

Comment: select number,count(*) as total from tb01 group by number union all  select number,count(*) as total from tb02 group by number... then how should I again group by?

Comment: @jarlh, can you help with an answer

Comment: I don't get the logic here - is it guaranteed that the first five number in every table is  the same number if not then  what?

Comment: @P.Salmon, I have mentioned that I have 5 different datasets.. So first 5 numbers are not same always.I need to get the union from all 5 datasets and get the count of that particular number count of each dataset.

Comment: Still trailing - so how do you decide which five numbers from these 5 tables are presented in the result

Comment: Limit 5 used to just get the sample.. I dont need to limit 5..Sorry. I will edit the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a job for JOINs and subqueries. My answer will consider three tables. It should be obvious how to expand it to five.

Your first subquery: get all possible `number`s.

```sql
            SELECT number FROM tb01 UNION
            SELECT number FROM tb02 UNION
            SELECT number FROM tb03
```

Then you have a subquery for each table to get the count.

```sql
          SELECT number, COUNT(*) AS total
            FROM tb02 GROUP BY number
```

Then you LEFT JOIN everything and SELECT from that.

```sql
SELECT numbers.number, 
       tb01.total tb01, 
       tb02.total tb02,
       tb03.total tb03
  FROM (
            SELECT number FROM tb01 UNION
            SELECT number FROM tb02 UNION
            SELECT number FROM tb03
        ) numbers
  LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT number, COUNT(*) AS total
            FROM tb01 GROUP BY number
        ) tb01 ON numbers.number = tb01.number
  LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT number, COUNT(*) AS total
            FROM tb02 GROUP BY number
        ) tb02 ON numbers.number = tb02.number
  LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT number, COUNT(*) AS total
            FROM tb03 GROUP BY number
        ) tb03 ON numbers.number = tb01.number
```

You can add `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses to that overall query as necessary.

The first subquery together with the LEFT JOIN ensures that you get results even if some of your tables are missing `number` rows. (Some DBMSs have FULL OUTER JOIN, but MySQL does not.)

**Pro tip**: If you use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`, you get an *unpredictable* subset of your rows. *Unpredictable* is worse than *random*, because you get the same subset in testing with small tables, but when your tables grow you may start getting different subsets. You'll never catch the problem in unit testing. `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is a serious error.